# Mapping <Shift>-Arrows to selecting characters/lines

Tags: vim, vi

I started to use vim recently, but I miss the character/line selection methods from other text editors. By default vim maps `<S-Up>`, `<S-Down>` to jumping one page up/down and I want to remap these to text selection.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: r u not having page up and page down on ur keyboard??

Comment: The question is different. I want to map <Shift>-<Up> to work as line selection and <Shift>-<Left> to work as char selection.

Comment: the answer about vim's "keymodel" option is the best answer to this question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vim doesn't bend to that easily in my opinion. The terminal one doesn't even recognize Shift-Up in my case! I thought the `v` (character-wise selection) or `V` (line-wise selection) was among the easier concepts to learn about vi/vim.

If this works (can't test right now), this is something you'll want:

```
" activate visual mode in normal mode
nmap <S-Up> V
nmap <S-Down> V
" these are mapped in visual mode
vmap <S-Up> k
vmap <S-Down> j
" 
" etc...
" similarly <S-Left>, <S-Right> for v
```

Comment: Thanks and that works as expected. I understand you wouldn't recommend it though?

Comment: @AlexeiDanchenkov, indeed I don't recommend it. It breaks against the vim model of not having to repeatedly hack single keys to get forward. You would miss text objects as well.

Comment: I would add the extra up/down on the move from normal mode to visual mode, and not do visual line mode to make it feel like it does in every other mac app - "nmap <S-Up> v<Up>"

Answer (score 33):

I completed @escrafford mapping with insert mode's ones:

```
" shift+arrow selection
nmap <S-Up> v<Up>
nmap <S-Down> v<Down>
nmap <S-Left> v<Left>
nmap <S-Right> v<Right>
vmap <S-Up> <Up>
vmap <S-Down> <Down>
vmap <S-Left> <Left>
vmap <S-Right> <Right>
imap <S-Up> <Esc>v<Up>
imap <S-Down> <Esc>v<Down>
imap <S-Left> <Esc>v<Left>
imap <S-Right> <Esc>v<Right>
```

Also mapping usual copy/cut/paste like this you can return to insert mode after select+copy, for example.

```
vmap <C-c> y<Esc>i
vmap <C-x> d<Esc>i
map <C-v> pi
imap <C-v> <Esc>pi
imap <C-z> <Esc>ui
```

Now you can start a shift+arrow selection from any mode, then C-c to copy, and then C-v to paste. You always end in insert mode, so you have also C-z to undo.

I think this approaches more to the 'expected standard' behaviour for a text editor yu are asking for.

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but where do you add these mappings?

Comment: in any of the files mentioned by `vim --version | grep vimrc`. just add it somewhere in the file (you might need to create it)

Comment: Glad I found this. I was almost reduced to tears, misfiring an entire page select pm 30% of the time. For some reason this page was hard to for me find on google, so I will try to help the keyword search a little :) 


(((vim disable shift jump. shift in visual mode vim. remove shift arrow keys vim visual mode. remove shift key vim visual mode.)))

I can rest easy now that my cursor won't jump around like a jack russel terrier if I ever happen to hold shift too long after a Shift+V

Comment: Paste command should be `P`, not `p`. `p` paste after current charactr, while `P` paste before current character, as in normal Ctrl-v paste.

Answer (score 33):

There's an specific option for this: [`keymodel`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'keymodel'):

```
'keymodel' 'km'     string  (default "")
            global
            {not in Vi}
    List of comma separated words, which enable special things that keys
    can do.  These values can be used:
       startsel Using a shifted special key starts selection (either
            Select mode or Visual mode, depending on "key" being
            present in 'selectmode').
       stopsel  Using a not-shifted special key stops selection.
    Special keys in this context are the cursor keys, <End>, <Home>,
    <PageUp> and <PageDown>.
    The 'keymodel' option is set by the |:behave| command.
```

**TL;DR**: To enable the behavior you want, use:

```
set keymodel=startsel
```

If you also want to leave visual mode when using `<Up>` or `<Down>` without `<Shift>` pressed, you can use:

```
set keymodel=startsel,stopsel
```

Comment: mindbending! why is this not marked as answer and upvoted? is there something wrong with it? it works perfectly, and thanks for the nice explaination! so is the keymodel only the shift key?

Comment: this is the best answer to this question

Answer (score 19):

Slightly different from progo's answer - this gives the same feel as mac apps normally have:

```
nmap <S-Up> v<Up>
nmap <S-Down> v<Down>
nmap <S-Left> v<Left>
nmap <S-Right> v<Right>
vmap <S-Up> <Up>
vmap <S-Down> <Down>
vmap <S-Left> <Left>
vmap <S-Right> <Right>
```

The differences being switch to visual mode instead of visual line mode, and not losing the initial up/down etc keystroke.

Comment: I'd prefer this answer, way better approach in my opinion. Also works great on Linux, too.

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution that is easier to execute. The command ':behave mswin' does all that is needed to use shift plus cursor keys to select text. Works from any mode. It also supports Cmd-c, Cmd-v and Cmd-x. It works in MacVim but I did not try other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely recommended that you don't remap this feature. Simply switching to visual mode and using `v` and the arrow keys is a better idea. `V` will select the entire line, `v$` will select to the end of the line and `vw` will select the next word. There are many more commands you can use to select different lines and words. Learning these commands will not only be useful for selecting but also useful for editing your files more efficiently.

Comment: I didn't know about this mode.  Thanks!

Comment: sounds like a lot more key pressing as opposed to just hold ctrl and shift instead.

Answer (score 1):

This mapping keeps insert mode during selection (visual mode) and it starts on the correct position. You can also select a word to the left or right using Ctrl-Shift-Left/Right (if your terminal supports it):

```
" Select with shift + arrows
inoremap    <S-Left>              <Left><C-o>v
inoremap    <S-Right>             <C-o>v
inoremap    <S-Up>                <Left><C-o>v<Up><Right>
inoremap    <S-Down>              <C-o>v<Down><Left>
imap        <C-S-Left>            <S-Left><C-Left>
imap        <C-S-Right>           <S-Right><C-Right>
vnoremap    <S-Left>              <Left>
vnoremap    <S-Right>             <Right>
vnoremap    <S-Up>                <Up>
vnoremap    <S-Down>              <Down>

" Auto unselect when not holding shift
vmap        <Left>                <Esc>
vmap        <Right>               <Esc><Right>
vmap        <Up>                  <Esc><Up>
vmap        <Down>                <Esc><Down>
```

This may be useful for quickly selecting small parts when you're in insert mode but I recommend using the default commands for selecting larger parts.

Answer (score -1):

I've written this to be able to navigate using `Alt+hjkl` (and friends) and select using `Alt+HJLK` when both in insert, visual and normal mode.

So the same can be applied to normal arrow keys as well

```
let hjklfriends = ['h','j','k','l','w','e','b','W','E','B', 'n', 'N', 'y', 'Y', 'p', 'P']

" define if using alt (it works in neovim) or Escape key.
function! Meta(key)
  if has('nvim')
        return "<A-" . a:key . ">"
    else
        return "<Esc>" . a:key
    endif
endfunction

execute 'noremap! ' . Meta('h') . ' <left>'
execute 'noremap! ' . Meta('j') . ' <down>'
execute 'noremap! ' . Meta('k') . ' <up>'
execute 'noremap! ' . Meta('l') . ' <right>'
execute 'noremap! ' . Meta('b') . ' <C-Left>'
execute 'noremap! ' . Meta('w') . ' <C-Right>'
execute 'noremap! ' . Meta('e') . ' <C-Right>'

for k in hjklfriends
  execute 'imap ' . Meta(k) . ' <C-o>' . k

  if k =~ '[a-z]'
    execute 'imap ' . Meta(toupper(k)) . ' <C-o>v' . k
    execute 'vmap ' . Meta(toupper(k)) . ' ' . k
    execute 'nmap ' . Meta(toupper(k)) . ' v' . k
  endif
endfor
```

Answer (score -1):

Modified from [@RubenCaro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25167579/1818110).

The issue is: [when escaping from insert mode, the cursor will be shifted to the left by one.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11402/why-does-esc-move-the-cursor-back-in-vim/11405) This makes the behaviour of the keys , , and  in insert mode different from the behaviour of other generic text editors.
Assuming that the goal is to make those keys behave like generic editor, the mapping should be slightly modified to:

```
" shift+arrow selection
nmap <S-Up> v<Up>
nmap <S-Down> v<Down>
nmap <S-Left> v<Left>
nmap <S-Right> v<Right>
vmap <S-Up> <Up>
vmap <S-Down> <Down>
vmap <S-Left> <Left>
vmap <S-Right> <Right>
imap <S-Up> <Esc>v<Up>
imap <S-Down> <Esc>vlvv<Down>
imap <S-Left> <Esc>v<Left>
imap <S-Right> <Esc>vlvv<Right>

vmap <C-c> y<Esc>i
vmap <C-x> d<Esc>i
map <C-v> pi
imap <C-v> <Esc>pli
imap <C-z> <Esc>ui
```