# Trying to get some mappings to work in vim

Tags: vim

There are a few mappings I want to work so I can use VIM more like a regular text editor I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25167579/3536548) which seems to work for most people, most people not including me.

The idea is to use shift plus arrow keys for selection from normal mode but instead it just causes my curser to get stuck and does nothing else.

Also I'm trying to get [multi-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) working in vim but when I use my key mappings I get this error

```
E78: Unknown mark
```

Here are my [key-mappings](https://github.com/Thermatix/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/config/mapings.vim):

```
" Buffer switching
map <leader>p :bp<CR> " \p previous buffer
map <leader>n :bn<CR> " \n next buffer
map <leader>d :bd<CR> " \d delete buffer

" Increment numbers
nnoremap <A-a> <C-a>
nnoremap <A-x> <C-x>

map <Leader>c :call vroom#RunTestFile()<CR>
map <Leader>s :call vroom#RunNearestTest()<CR>
map <leader>t :A<CR> " \t to jump to test file
map <leader>r :r<cr> " \t to jump to related file
map <leader>E :Explore .<cr> " \E to open file explorer in root
map <leader>e :Explore<cr> " \e to open file explorer in current dir

"nerd tree mapings
map <C-n> <plug>NERDTreeTabsToggle<CR>

"shit plus arrow for selectio mode
" shift+arrow selection
nmap <S-Up> v<Up>
nmap <S-Down> v<Down>
nmap <S-Left> v<Left>
nmap <S-Right> v<Right>
vmap <S-Up> <Up>
vmap <S-Down> <Down>
vmap <S-Left> <Left>
vmap <S-Right> <Right>
imap <S-Up> <Esc>v<Up>
imap <S-Down> <Esc>v<Down>
imap <S-Left> <Esc>v<Left>
imap <S-Right> <Esc>v<Right>

"copy and pasting
vmap <C-c> y<Esc>i
vmap <C-x> d<Esc>i
map <C-v> pi
imap <C-v> <Esc>pi
imap <C-z> <Esc>ui

"multi-cursor mappings"
let g:multi_cursor_next_key='<leader>d'
let g:multi_cursor_prev_key='<leader>s'
let g:multi_cursor_skip_key='<C-x>'
let g:multi_cursor_quit_key='<Esc>'

" Removing escape
ino jj <esc>
cno jj <c-c>
vno v <esc>

" Remove highlights with leader + enter
nmap <Leader><CR> :nohlsearch<cr>

" Ruby hash syntax conversion
nnoremap <F12> :%s/:\([^ ]*\)\(\s*\)=>/\1:/g<return>
```

I'd also like to add I'm very new to vim beyond basic text editing so I don't doubt that I'm doing things wrong, ignorant to some aspect, etc, so please take that into account when answering.

Pressing `shift+left` results in `D` being outputted to the terminal.

Pressing `shift+right` results in `C` being outputted to the terminal.

Comment: Are you aware of visual mode? Why didn't you prefer that to select text? You can use that along with text motions and select a word, line or paragraph or even multiple of these!

Comment: Is this in the terminal? There is no guarantee, that the terminal can actually see and recognize those keycodes

Comment: @ Christian Brabandt it recognises I've pressed shift, just does somthing different, not sure what it's actually doing tbh. Whats the best way to test if it does recognise the keys?

Comment: Like @SibiCoder said, are you aware of visual mode? In normal mode, just press `v` to start selecting and then navigate (even using arrow keys)

Comment: It seems like you're trying to force vim to work like the other editors. Also, this "shift+arrow" to select is very limiting compared to what vim already offers out of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer (eventually) and solved the other problem as welll.

The solution lies in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19088) on a unixstack question.

First you need to tell vim the escape key codes used by your terminal.
I have done this [here](https://github.com/Thermatix/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/config/key_codes.vim):

```
function Allmap(mapping)
  execute 'map' a:mapping
  execute 'map!' a:mapping
endfunction

call Allmap('   <ESC>[1;2       <S>')
call Allmap('   <ESC>[1;2A      <S-Up>')
call Allmap('   <ESC>[1;2B      <S-Down>')
call Allmap('   <ESC>[1;2C      <S-Right>')
call Allmap('   <ESC>[1;2D      <S-Left>')
call Allmap('   <ESC>[1;2d      <S-d>')
call Allmap('   <ESC>[1;2s      <S-s>')
```

Then I just attach the commands I want to the declared key mappings:

```
map <S-Up> v<Up>
nmap <S-Down> v<Down>
nmap <S-Left> v<Left>
nmap <S-Right> v<Right>
vmap <S-Up> <Up>
vmap <S-Down> <Down>
vmap <S-Left> <Left>
vmap <S-Right> <Right>
imap <S-Up> <Esc>v<Up>
imap <S-Down> <Esc>v<Down>
imap <S-Left> <Esc>v<Left>
imap <S-Right> <Esc>v<Right>


"multi-cursor mappings"
let g:multi_cursor_next_key='<S-d>'
let g:multi_cursor_prev_key='<S-s>'
```

Comment: What you are actually doing is selecting through visual mode, which is already available.