# How to use <S-Up> & <S-Down> in Terminal.app & vim

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I'd like to map `<Shift> + <Arrow Keys>` to select text, just like expected behavior in something like sublime text (idea comes from this: [Mapping <Shift>-Arrows to selecting characters/lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721732/mapping-shift-arrows-to-selecting-characters-lines)). Using the setup I have below, `<S-Left>` and `<S-Right>` **does** work, but `<S-Up>` and `<S-Down>` **does not** work. Believe Terminal.app needs to add a keyboard action, or something?

In `~/.vimrc`:

```
nmap <S-Up> v<Up>
nmap <S-Down> v<Down>
nmap <S-Left> v<Left>
nmap <S-Right> v<Right>
```

I see that in vim (in insert mode, then `<C-v> + <S-Up>` gets me this `^[OA`, and `<C-v> + <S-Down>` gets me this `^[OB`.

In Terminal.app preferences (default setup):

[image: default Terminal.app keyboard settings]

Comment: Why don't you try to get used to Vim instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out Terminal.app doesn't send the shift+up or shift+down codes to the terminal.

From here: https://github.com/timothybasanov/terminal-app-function-keys

Add this codes to the Terminal.app profile:

```
⇧↑ \033[1;2A
⇧↓ \033[1;2B
```